# Testlink 1.9.10 requirements import not working

Tags: testlink

I am new to Testlink and I have successfully installed Testlink 1.9.10. I am able to import the test cases successfully but when I try to import the requirements it says "Import Done" but nothing gets imported. I tried lower version 1.9.7 and there also I am not able to import the requirements.

I tried both CSV and XML format. I need help to see if I am missing some steps.

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Regards
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and searched through TestLink official forums and found out it is a bug, but patch has not been provided.